# How to evaluate a piece of elisp code after all install packages are loaded?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have installed several Emacs packages by `M-x install-package`. The starter-kit package hide the tool-bar and menu bar of emacs but I want them show back.

I added

`(tool-bar-mode t)`

in my ~/.emacs file but it seems get evaluated before starter-kit package get loaded.

Where should I put those code if I want evaluate them when all installed packages finished loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `package.el` file, in particular:

```
(defcustom package-enable-at-startup t
  "Whether to activate installed packages when Emacs starts.
If non-nil, packages are activated after reading the init file
and before `after-init-hook'.  Activation is not done if
`user-init-file' is nil (e.g. Emacs was started with \"-q\").

Even if the value is nil, you can type \\[package-initialize] to
activate the package system at any time."
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'package
 :version "24.1")
```

So you can call `package-initialize` early in your `.emacs` and then overwrite what you need such as `tool-bar-mode`.

You could also put your overwrites in the `after-init-hook`.

Comment: Also read `C-h i g (emacs) Package Installation RET` beginning from "The reason automatic package loading occurs after loading the init file is that user options only receive their customized values after loading the init file, including user options which affect the packaging system."

Comment: Using `after-init-hook` (as already mentioned by Nicolas Dudebout) is probably the safest approach. Something like `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'my-after-init-hook) (defun my-after-init-hook () ...)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the starter kit package is in library called "starter-kit", this should work:

```
(eval-after-load "starter-kit"
   '(tool-bar-mode t))
```

Comment: Is there a way to eval a piece of Elisp when the last installed package finished loading,without specifying a particular package name?